# Can't get user avatar

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get user's avatars for a welcome message but when someone joins it never shows it. I've tried many different methods. Here is my current code.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0000FF')
    .addField('Welcome!', `Welcome to the server, ${member}! Go to <#channel> for the rules, then grab some roles at <#channel>!`)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('693219932904751177').send(exampleEmbed);


});
```

Comment: Are you using Discord.js v12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do it add a `()` behind the `.displayAvatarURL`

So the line would look like this:

```js
.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
```